# How compare two paired list in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logic, md5sum

I'm trying to compare a remote `md5sum` result from some files into a server, with my local `md5sum` files and those that match, the `hash` and the `filename` should be removed from the local server.

The whole algorithm about get the `md5sum` from both is done, I have something like this:

```
remote_list="<hash values> <filename>.gz"
local_list="<hash values> <filename>.gz"
```

But now I need to do the comparison between what have into both lists.
I was thinking in do two `for's` but I wonder if this is a good approach (and a efficient one).

So far I did this:

```
#!/bin/bash
datacenter="amazon"
hostname=`hostname`;
path="backup/server245"

s3=`s3cmd ls --list-md5 s3://company-backup/company/"$datacenter"/"$hostname"/"$path"/`;
s3_list=$(echo "$s3" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4,5 | sed 's= .*/= =');
echo "$s3_list"

locally=`md5sum /"$path"/*.gz`;
echo "$locally";

locally_list=$(echo "$locally" | sed 's= .*/= =');
echo "$locally_list";
```

Which give me this output:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e #md5 from remote folder
41eae9b40d23de2f02bf07635870f6d0 app.20121117040001.gz #remote file
541b1bf78682f48867cc99dbb53c4c3a app.20121118040001.gz #remote file
31d90af7969f5003b27f68e27e7f2cb1 app.gz #remote file
31d90af7969f5003b27f68e27e7f2cb1  /backup/server245/app.gz #local file
```

So follow the idea, I have `app.gz` in both places, so I can delete it from my local my machine.
Any idea or suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider a match only if both the md5sum and the filename are the same, then it's simple:

```
sort remote_list local_list | uniq -d > duplicate_list
```

(Important note: this assumes that there are no repeats in either of the file lists. There certainly shouldn't be if you've done the md5sums correctly.)

Comment: I tried your approach, but it gives me this error `sort: open failed: 31d90af7969f5003b27f68e27e7f2cb1: No such file or directory`, do you know why is that ?

Comment: @ValterHenrique: Sorry, I thought that `remote_list` and `local_list` were files, not shell variables. If you want to use variables, you'll need to pipe both of them through sort: `(echo "$s3_list"; echo "$locally_list") | sort | uniq -d`. That will return both md5sum and filename; you'll have to use `cut` to extra the filename. I think you should also try to find a better way of normalizing the path names, since your way loses all path information.